# Which of these linear algebra statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

let V= R^5 be equipped with the usual euclidean inner-product. Which
of the following statements are true?

a). If W and Z are subspaces of V such that both of them are of dimension
 3, then there exists z ∈ Z such that z is not equal to 0 and z ⊥ W.

b). There exists a non-zero linear map T : V → V such that ker(T) ∩ W not equal to {0} for every subspace W of V of dimension 4.

c). Let W be a subspace of V of dimension 3. Let T : V →W be a linear map
which is surjective and let S : W → V be a linear map which is injective
Then, there exists x ∈ V such that x is not equal 0 such that S ◦ T(x) = 0.

My attempts: for option a) i take dim V=5 and dim w=3,dimz=3,,and i know that  Dim(w+z)=5 =DimV....Dim(w+z)= dimw + dimz - dim w ∩ dimz = 3+3-0 =6 and i know that dim w ∩ dimz={0} because z ⊥ W.  but dim(z+w) =5 not equal to 6..so option a) is incorrect.

for option b)  ker(T)∩ W is not equal {0},,that mean kernel(T) =1  so by rank nullity theorem dim W of V =4  as we know that DimV = 5 and dim null(w) =1 so we get Dimrange(W) =4  so the option B is correct.

for option C)  i don't know...i have no any hint  to solve this ...

if anbody try to rectified my mistake i would be very thankful..

Comment: a) If W=Z this is clearly unachieveable

Comment: how can u say that it is unachievable @ aleksejs Fomin

Comment: You should post using some basic MathJax.

Comment: If a vector is orthogonal to the entire space, it is orthogonal to all vectors in it. If W=Z, the vector z will be at least certainly not orthogonal to itself in W

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: thanks for Maths jax tutorial i will try next time  @ shaun

Comment: Can you please define the circle operator in c)

Comment: S ◦ T(x) = 0 is composition function@ aleksejas fomin

Answer (score 1):

a) False. Take any two equal spaces $W$ and $Z$.

b) True. Let $T$ be such that $\operatorname{rank}T=1$. Then $\dim\ker T=4$ and, in a $5$-dimensional space, any two $2$-dimensional subspaces have non-trivial intersection.

c) True. $\operatorname{rank}T\leqslant 3$ and therefore $\operatorname{rank}(S\circ T)\leqslant 3$. Since $\dim V=5$, $\det(S\circ T)=0$ and therefore $\ker(S\circ T)\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: im not getting rank T= 1 for opton b)....and for option c)there exists x ∈ V such that x is not equal 0 ....and .how can u write  ker( S ◦ T) = 0,,,im not getting this line @ jose carlos santos

Comment: @legohlegoh What is it that you don't get for option b)? Concerning c), $\det(S\circ T)=0\iff\operatorname{rank}(S\circ T)<\dim V$.

Comment: for option b) kernel T= 1 that mean Rank T = 4 by rank nullity theorem @ jose carlo santos

Comment: @legohlegoh Perhaps that you are not aware of the fact that $\operatorname{rank}T=\dim\operatorname{im}T$.

Comment: every subspace W of V of dimension 4. ...here dimension of the image of T =4 ,,,then  how can u write  dim imT =1  @jose carlos santos

Comment: @legohlegoh What makes you think that $\dim\operatorname{im}T=4$? It is equal to $1$, not $4$.

Comment: ACCORDING TO MY QUESTION IT IS GIVEN THAT ...every subspace W of V of dimension 4......so dimension imT= 4..@ JOSE CARLOS santos .....

Comment: @legohlegoh **Wrong**. Do you really belieave that there is a $5$-dimensional vector space such that every subspace has dimension $4$? What I proved is that there is an endomorphism $T$ of $V$ such that, *when* a subspace $W$ of $V$ has dimension $4$, $\ker T\cap W\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: thanks,, now i got it..in 5 dimensional vector space that every subspace need not be has dimension 4,,@ jose carlos santos

Comment: What if in part a) W not equal to V?

Comment: @Tony Then the statement will still be false, since $W\cap Z\ne\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

a) Unachieveable for W=Z, because any $z \in Z$ will be orthogonal to itself $z \in W$.

b) If T is non-zero, its kernel dimension is at most 4. In 5D space any two 4D subspaces will have shared dimensions, and hence they will have intersections along basis vectors of that dimension. So it is true

c) Kernel of an injective function is $\{0\}$, so the output of $T$ can not be 0. But $T$ can map to the kernel of $S$. If the kernel of $S$ is at least 3D, then it will intersect with the output of $T$. The kernel of $S$ is 2D, and it is exactly disjoint with $W$, since $S:W\rightarrow V$, so it is not possible

Comment: As subspaces always contain the zero vector, your argument for b) will not work.

Comment: Ah I guess I misunderstood the question, sorry :)
I thought that they did not intersect at all

Comment: You can't have two parallel spaces that both contain the zero vector, as parallel spaces shouldn't intersect. Try drawing two parallel lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that both contain the zero point but are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt for a):

> i take dim V=5 and dim w=3,dimz=3,,and i know that Dim(w+z)=5 =DimV....Dim(w+z)= dimw + dimz - dim w ∩ dimz = 3+3-0 =6 and i know that dim w ∩ dimz={0} because z ⊥ W. but dim(z+w) =5 not equal to 6..so option a) is incorrect.

It is not clear which question you're *trying* to answer, but your statement seems completely irrelevant.  My only guess as to your thought process is that you were trying to fit in the formula $\dim (W+Z)= \dim W + \dim Z - \dim (W ∩ Z)$  somehow.

If your goal is to prove that a) is **not** always the case, then you should be looking for a counterexample.  That is, find specific subspaces $Z,W$ of $\Bbb R^5$ where no element of $Z$ is orthogonal to $W$.

Your attempt for b):

> ker(T)∩ W is not equal {0},,that mean kernel(T) =1 so by rank nullity theorem dim W of V =4 as we know that DimV = 5 and dim null(w) =1 so we get Dimrange(W) =4 so the option B is correct.

It is not true that kernel(T) = 1 since kernel(T) is a subspace an 1 is a number.  It is also not necessarily true that $\dim \ker(T) = 1$.

Again, you're missing the fact that to correctly answer this question, you should construct an example.  For instance: we can take $T:V \to V$ to be the orthogonal projection onto $V^\perp$.

For c): use the rank nullity theorem to deduce that $\dim \ker(T) \neq 0$.  Now, if $T(x) = 0$, then we also have $S(T(x)) = 0$.

Comment: thanks  a lot @Omnomnomnom for rectifying my mistakes...